Image and text in tcolorbox; How to make the text span remainder of interior width?
I have an image and text inside a tcolorbox. I'd like to make the text fill the remaining horizontal interior space that the image doesn't fill. Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry} % Page margins
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\noindent\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red,boxrule=0.5pt,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,drop small lifted shadow]
     \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Pictures/combo.jpg}%
     \parbox{\textwidth}{Here is some text abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc!}
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}

produces:

If I now change the fourth-to-last line to
\parbox{\textwidth}{Here is some...

Then I see this:

Therefore I assume I should change the fourth-to-last line to
\parbox{\textwidth-2cm}{Here is some...

since the image is 2cm wide. However then I see this:

How do I make the text span the remaining horizontal space in the tcolorbox?
Lastly, once it has spanned the space how do I center both the image and the text vertically in the tcolorbox? So that if the image is bigger, the text will be centered vertically on it; if the text is larger in y, then the image will be centered on it. Hopefully that makes sense. I just want everything centered vertically always.

I'd use a sidebyside box:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,lefthand width=2cm, lower separated=false]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

  \tcblower

  Here is some text abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc!
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


